# is windows presentation foundation available to c++ developers?

Tags: c++, wpf

i read about window presentation foundation and i got a book

> windows presentation foundation
>   unleashed.

But to my surprise, the code was in c#.

**Question:**

Is wpf available to c++ developers? if not Why. Thanks

Comment: I'm not surprised, it's MS's most popular language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET can certainly be worked with [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI), and that should extend to WPF as well.

Comment: Again note that C++/CLI has more in common with C# than it does C++. +1.

Comment: Sure, but you could also note an obvious thing that C# and C++ have very much in common, too -- in both syntax and semantics. So what? As long as it helps making things done without creating too many problems, it's good, I think.

Comment: I'd like to add, that C# is basically very similar to C++. If you know C++, C# will be a breeze to learn. The major changes are only in the way memory and objects are handled (with a garbage collector, instead of new/delete and no implicit automatic variables, which only simplifies stuff). There is more syntactic sugar, but otherwise it's almost the same. As a result, it's much easier to handle than C++, with less gotchas to worry about. So fear not!

Comment: Not really. In C++ you can have things like destructors. On the CLR, you cannot. (The CLR does have something similar, called "Finalizers" but these are quite different from destructors because destructors are deterministic, finalizers are not) C++/CLI also encourages use of things like reflection, and contains all the casting safety and such provided by the CLR, and doesn't have C++'s template power (C#-like generics only). It's really C# using C++ syntax, not C++.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Often, it doesn't matter a lot whether the CLR has destructors. Assembly doesn't have them, either, and that hasn't stopped C++ compilers. It only breaks when you assume that GC and destructors can mix. Also, [C++/CLI does have templates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slippman/archive/2004/08/05/209606.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

WPF was built for a managed environment, so if you want to use native C++ with WPF, there will be hurdles and you will have to mix unmanaged and unmanaged code. But really, a .NET language is the preferred way to use WPF.

See: [WPF and Win32 Interoperability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742522.aspx)

Comment: Well, WPF and Win32 can interoperate, but native code still cannot control WPF. The interop supported here just embeds a Win32 window inside the WPF segment and passes around a `HWND` that native code can play with. But you certainly don't get things like XAML in C++.

Answer (score 0):

WPF is available to c++ developers if they use managed C++.

Comment: There's no version of "Managed C++" (Which last existed in Visual Studio 2005) which supports WPF. C++/CLI supports it, but is more like C# than C++.

Answer (score 0):

C++ cannot interface with WPF because WPF is a technology based on managed code. WPF's main design goal is built around the CLR's event system, reflection features, and object framework.

- In a WPF app, you construct an object graph using a XAML file. The runtime uses reflection in order to bind specific elements in the XAML to real objects to instantiate at runtime. This cannot be done in C++ because C++ does not support reflection.
- WPF notifies code-behind using events (a signals/slots system). This wouldn't be as easily possible in C++ because C++ has no native event system. (Though there are things like `boost::signals` available)
- WPF's classes are all built from managed code.

You can access WPF from `C++/CLI`, but C++/CLI actually has more in common with C# than it does with C++. It's code operates exactly like C# does, but it uses C++'s syntax (which to me doesn't really make sense... more people complain about C++'s syntax than almost anything else in the language!).

If you want to use WPF, I'd recommend just sticking with C#.

Comment: C++ can interface with anything, as long as it's known how to do that. It's a low-level language, compilable to a variety of hardware and software platforms, .NET CLI included.

Comment: C# reflection can be substituted with RTTI and plain old OOP (with restrictions, maybe). Events are fine in C++, because, again, it boils down to exchanging messages/calling callbacks. This is how Windows worked since it was 1.0 (it was written in 'C with classes', after all). Sure, it may not have all the special syntactic sugar of C# for events, but it will work fine. Again, managed code is not a problem for C++. C++/CLI provides everything necessary.

Comment: On the other hand, where C++/CLI might need a special API to access some of the WPF's features, it may still lack that. But it's an issue of .NET/WPF API, not C++.

Comment: @deemoowoor: XAML takes a class name and creates that class at runtime, based on it's name. Nothing like C++'s RTTI does that. And, no, WPF has absolutely nothing to do with messages or anything like that. In this respect it's more like DirectX than Win32 -- the Windows subsystem doesn't manage it at all. Open a WPF app up in Spy++ if you don't believe me.

Comment: @deemoowoor: Oh, and you can't compile C++ to the CLR, because C++ has deterministic destruction of objects, which you can't get on the CLR (There's no way to force it explicitly to delete anything). (Unless you implemented something like a full VM on top of the CLR)

Comment: @deemoowoor: BTW, thanks for the downvote. I'll reconsider before upvoting your answer next time.

Comment: @Billy ONeal, check your sources there, pal! RTTI does give you access to class names and it helps with dynamic typing in C++. Also, check out the Factory pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern , which allows you to map specific class creation to any strings you like. I know, that WPF is XML-based, it's not the first ever window API to do that. wxWidgets' XRC comes to mind http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/XRC

Comment: @deemoowoor: Yes, it will give you the class name given a pointer to an instance of a class. But you can't get a pointer to an instance of a class given a class name. Sure, you could implement reflection-like features in C++, but there's certainly no standard for that. How do you expect something like WPF to be written to your completely nonstandard "reflection" implementation?

Comment: @Billy ONeal, no need to make it personal. My downvote was because I believe your advice is simply misguiding, nothing more. C++/CLI is compiled as normal C++, it's just made to _interoperate_ nicely with CLI, not use it exclusively.

Comment: @deemoowoor: No it is not. Take any piece of C++ code that uses the RAII pattern. Compile as C++/CLI. Watch it explode. Enjoy. As for "personal", I think your answer is "misguided" too. But it's close enough to what the OP wants, and I added a comment to indicate to the OP that it really isn't C++.